# How to check for a file type within an AWS Lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Just a quick question, I want to know if it is possible to have a lambda function that is triggered by an SNS stream or an S3 upload, and how I would go about doing it. I am trying to set up an email notifier that will send me an email when an object is uploaded and tell me what type of file was uploaded. Thanks!

Comment: @HankD I noticed that you are suggesting a lot of tag-only edits.  Please be careful and address all aspects of a post when retagging.  For example, be sure to remove noise (like "thanks") and flag off-topic questions for closure.  In general mass retagging is frowned upon, but feel free to ask question on meta for dealing with large scale retagging.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has published an example where it listens for objects to be uploaded to S3 and then the Lambda function will copy the new object to another bucket.

The sample walkthrough can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser.html

In your case, your handler would:

1. examine the file extension of the uploaded file
2. use Amazon SES to send an email to you